# Extension function on enumerator, `values()` unavailable?

Tags: enums, kotlin, kotlin-extension

If I try to type:

```
enum class EGraphicsAPIConvention(@get:JvmName("i") val i: Int) {    
   API_DirectX(0),    
   API_OpenGL(1)    
}

fun EGraphicsAPIConvention.of(i: Int) = values().first { it.i == i }
```

The compiler complains:

> unresolved reference values

`this.values()` doesn't help neither

Why don't I have `values()` available?

Comment: use `EGraphicsAPIConvention.values()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fun EGraphicsAPIConvention.of(i: Int)` is adding [an extension method](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) to all `EGraphicsAPIConvention` instances so that you can write `EGraphicsAPIConvention. API_DirectX.of(1)`.

Kotlin currently does not provide a way to write an extension function at a class level.

However you can make use of `companion object` to get the desired behavior like so:

```
enum class EGraphicsAPIConvention(@get:JvmName("i") val i: Int) {
    API_DirectX(0),
    API_OpenGL(1);

    companion object {
        fun of(i: Int) = values().first { it.i == i }
    }
}
```

And then use it: `EGraphicsAPIConvention.of(0)`